# Only MySqlParameter objects may be stored (C#)

Tags: c#, mysql, ado.net, mysql-connector

I researched this problem but didn't get tangible solution. For your information, I use our general library class for connection and never encountered such a problem. And also I want to say that project runs successfully on my local PC but not on server.

This is the code fragment which I get an error:

```
    queue_tablename = tablename;

    conn = myconn;
    writecomm = conn.CreateCommand();
    writecomm.CommandText = "insert into "+tablename+" (id,mtype,channel,dt,fromnumber,tonumber,smstext)" +
        "values (?id,?mtype,?channel,?dt,?fromnumber,?tonumber,?smstext)";
    writecomm.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("id", MySqlDbType.Int64));
    writecomm.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("mtype", MySqlDbType.VarChar));
    writecomm.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("channel", MySqlDbType.VarChar));
    writecomm.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("dt", MySqlDbType.DateTime));
    writecomm.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("fromnumber", MySqlDbType.VarChar));
    writecomm.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("tonumber", MySqlDbType.VarChar));
    writecomm.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("smstext", MySqlDbType.VarChar));
```

This line throws the exception:

```
writecomm.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("id", MySqlDbType.Int64));
```

> An unhandled exception of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException'
> occurred in MySql.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Only MySqlParameter objects may be stored

Comment: Should it be `?id` instead of `id` when you add the parameter?

Comment: You've missed question mark parameter sigil (`?`) when declaring `MySqlParameter`. Add the mark before parameter names & try again, or use .NET version of query parameters as `@`.

Comment: Try using '@' instead of '?'.

Comment: I said that this is our general connection library. And a lot of projects use it now without a problem. Also tried to use `?` and `@` when declaring parameter. None of them helps me.

Comment: That code is a default library of mysql.. And don't even say that it was created by your teammates. I didn't even use `?` that sign anymore. Now if it is working then go ahead.

Comment: @reds, are you kidding me? Don't you understand what I mean when I say library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem and hope it will help who tried above solution tips but can not solve.

The exception occurred because my connection library uses **MySql.Data.dll** version **6.2.2.2** but I added a reference of **6.9.9.0**. Change your MySql.Data reference, it will help you.

In my case, my company has another connection library which works with 6.9.9.0 version. That's why, I used the new one and everything is okay.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
Change `?` to `@` in your command text and,
```

add parameter like this,

```
writecomm.Parameters.Add("@id", MySqlDbType.Int64).Value = ParameterValue;
```

or

```
writecomm.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "@id",
                MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.Int64,
                Value=ParameterValue
            });
```

Comment: Maybe this doesn't work because of this `I said that this is our general connection library. And a lot of projects use it now without a problem. Also tried to use ? and @ when declaring parameter. None of them helps me.`

Answer (score 0):

Just adding another possible solution for this error: fully qualify the name of the MySqlParameter like so: `new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter(name, value)`.

I had a project in which both `MySqlConnector` and `MySql.Data.MySqlClient` were referenced and without the full qualification, it used the former, which then resulted in a casting error and the subsequent exception deep down in the db call.